# Checkbox state from HTML (JS) to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm new to JS and i want to receive the value from a variable in JS, send it by post (or ajax) to a PHP file, and see the text display. The thing is i've been trying different ways to do it but i always get a undefined index in php.

My code is below

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>PRUEBA AJAX JS PHP HTML</title>

  </head>
 <body>
 <H1>prueba</H1>

    <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" >  



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

$("#switch").change(function () 
    {
        var checked=$("#switch").attr("checked");

        if(checked)
        {
            $("switch").removeAttr("checked");
            console.log("estado apagado switch 1");
            var estados="1";
            $.post("accion.php", {estado: "david"});

        }else
        {

            $("#switch").attr("checked","checked");
            console.log("estado encendido switch 1");
            var estados="2";
            $.post("accion.php", {estado: "david 2"});
        }
    });


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

accion.php

```
 <?php 

 $est = $_POST['estado'];
 echo $est;

 if ($est=="david") {
 echo "no mameees";
 }else{
 echo "no mameees no se puso ";
 }


 ?>
```

Someone has any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let php check if the checkbox was checked or not in a success callback from $.post:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>PRUEBA AJAX JS PHP HTML</title>

  </head>
 <body>
 <H1>prueba</H1>

    <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" >  



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

$("#switch").change(function () 
    {
        var checkbox = $("#switch");

        $.post("accion.php", {estado: checkbox.val()}, function(data){
             $("h1").html(data);
        });

    });


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**accion.php**

```
<?php 

 $checkbox = isset($_POST['estado']) && $_POST['estado'] == 'on'; // 'on' is the default checkbox value when you don't specify it in html

 if ($checkbox) {
 echo "it's been checked";
 }else{
 echo "it wasn't checked";
 }


 ?>
```

**PS:** when working with ajax ( check out [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) options) i recommend using `dataType: 'json'` and your php should respond with a valid JSON, you have [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been trying all day ! I tried with ajax but it didnt work, that's why i used $.post !

Comment: It works with `$.ajax` too, but php can mess up the expected output if you're trying to access an undefined array, use `isset` before any other conditions to prevent `undefined index` in php

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#switch").change(function () {
       var checked=$("#switch").prop("checked");
         if(checked)
        {
        console.log(checked);
        
        }else{
         console.log(checked);
        }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Switch <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" >
```

Use `prop` instead of attr to find checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var checked = $('#switch').is(':checked');
```

instead of

```
var checked=$("#switch").attr("checked");
```